# How to remove links from text with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to clean up a database by removing links from tables.  So for column entry like this:

```
Thank you for the important information<br /><a href="http://www.cnn.com">Read More Here</a><br />  This is great.
```

i need to remove the entire link, so it would end up like this:

```
Thank you for the important information<br /><br />  This is great.
```

Is there a way to do this with a single UPDATE statement?
For extra credit, is there a way to remove the HTML semantics from the link, while leaving the content in the text?

Comment: @Joe SQL Server 2005 - added to tags, thx.

Comment: Can the text have more than 1 link?

Comment: How reliable does it have to be?  Is a naive algorithm such as the following acceptable?  Read up to '<a', discard up to '/a>', repeat to the end of the string.  (I don't know of any facility in SQL Server to directly parse the HTML and strip out specific parts.)

Comment: Why not process it with a few php lines of code? (Getting the data, transforming it the way you want and updating those records)

Answer (score 2):

Just try to find the starting and ending of the hrefj and replace it with a single space.

```
declare @StringToFix varchar(500)
set @StringToFix = 'Thank you for the important information<br /><a href="http://www.cnn.com">Read More'

select REPLACE(
        @stringtofix
        , Substring(@StringToFix
            , CHARINDEX('<a href=', @StringToFix) -- Starting Point
                           -- End Point - Starting Point with 4 more spaces
            , CHARINDEX('</a>', @StringToFix) 
                              - CHARINDEX('<a href=', @StringToFix) +4            )
        , ' '
    ) as ResultField
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like your@StringToFix lost its closing tag.  i.e. "Read More'" should be "Read More</a>'" ;)

Answer (score 0):

If all the links are done in a very consistent way than you can just use a regex replace of

```
'\<a href.*?\</a\>'
```

to an empty string.

I don't have SQL Server instance handy but the query in oracle would look something like:

```
update table
set col1 = REGEXP_REPLACE(col1,'\<a href.*?\</a\>', '', 1, 0, 'in');
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have REGEXP_REPLACE.

Comment: And links formed in a consistent way is not necessarily a realistic assumption (not for my case anyway :( ).

Answer (score 0):

I want share my sql script that remove ahref tag from text but leave anchor text.

**Source text:**

```
Visit <a href="http://google.com/">Google</a>, then <a href="http://bing.com">Bing</a>
```

**Result text:**

```
Visit Google, then Bing
```

**MS SQL CODE:**

```
declare @str nvarchar(max) = 'Visit <a href="http://google.com/">Google</a>, then <a href="http://bing.com">Bing</a>'

declare @aStart int = charindex('<a ', @str)
declare @aStartTagEnd int = charindex('>', @str, @aStart)

DECLARE @result nvarchar(max) = @str;

set @result = replace(@result, '</a>', '')

select @result

WHILE (@aStart > 0 and @aStartTagEnd > 0)
BEGIN

    declare @rep1 nvarchar(max) = substring(@result, @aStart, @aStartTagEnd + 1 - @aStart)

    set @result = replace(@result, @rep1, '')

    set @aStart = charindex('<a ', @result)
    set @aStartTagEnd = charindex('>', @result, @aStart)

END 

select @result
```